# Is there a Sharekit style plugin for sharing to Photo services?

Tags: iphone, sharing, photography

Is there an iOS plugin similar to Sharekit that would let me allow a user to share photos with other apps on their device? It would be great to make it easy to share to Camera+, Dropbox, InstaGram, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a generic framework that supports multiple photo sharing services. However, Dropbox has its own SDK that you can use. Instagram does not have a public API for uploading photos (i.e. you have to use the Instagram app).